# Сделать текст жирным в определенных местах текста

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте, есть текст в переменной, перед тем как вывести этот текст в textview, нужно выделить **жирным** участки текста от ( *скобки* до ) *скобки*, и от начала текста до знака - (*тире*).

Пробовал этот способ, но могу выделить только определенное кол-во слов, в данном случае два, а мне нужно что-бы конкретно от начала текста до - (тире). Потому-что в переменной текст меняется, и до тире может быть не два слова, и не три, а больше или меньше.

```
String[] tokens = e.split(" ");
                String twoFirstWords = tokens[0] + " " + tokens[1]; //первые два слова

                String content1 = e.replaceFirst(twoFirstWords, " "); //остальной текст

                SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
                SpannableString span1 = new SpannableString(twoFirstWords);
                SpannableString span2 = new SpannableString(content1);
                span1.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, twoFirstWords.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

                builder.append(span1);
                builder.append(span2);
                f2.setText(builder);
```

Comment: Приведите пример текста

Comment: @V.Makhnutin Алекса́ндр Македо́нский (Александр III Великий) — македонский царь с (336 до н. э.) из династии Аргеадов, полководец, создатель мировой державы, распавшейся после его смерти. В мусульманской традиции может отождествляться с легендарным царем Зуль-Карнайном. В западной историографии наиболее известен как Алекса́ндр Вели́кий. Ещё в Античности за Александром закрепилась слава одного из величайших полководцев в истории

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто сделайте сплит по тире и возьмите нулевой элемент, это и будет то, что находится до первого в тексте тире.

```
String[] tokens = e.split("—")
String beforeDash = tokens[0];
```

Текст между скобками можно искать следующим образом:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\(([^)]+)\\)").matcher(value);
while(m.find()) {
     doSomethingWithString(m.group(1));
}
```

Comment: Спасибо помогло, а как выделить и сделать жирным текст от скобки до скобки?

Comment: т.е. от скобки до скобки уже после тире? во всех скобках?

Comment: Во всех скобках

Comment: Дополнил ответ поиском выражений между скобок.

Comment: Подскажи пожалуйста, а как мне конкретно применить этот код к моему случаю, сделать шрифт жирнее?